# How to Highlight the particular Content element item in ItemsControl WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, prism

I have ItemControl which shows the list of a toggle-button, button name is displayed in numeric by binding content name.
What I need let's say I want to highlight the Togglebutton of numeric 24.
Is there any way I can get the Itemscontrol by index position and highlight the background in XAML triggers.
ex:I want to highlight togglebutton with id=9,when button is clicked.

```
<itemsControl>
<datatemplate>
<radtoggleButton content={binding id} ischecked={binding enabled}>
</datatemplate>
</itemsControl>
```

Is there any way to dynamically name the data template control items like below?
<radtoggleButton Name={bindiing} content={binding id} ischecked={binding enabled}>

Comment: Where does the index for the button come from? Is it a property on a view model, or in code-behind? What do you mean by "button name", the `x:Name` or the label on the button? How do you put the items in the control, via binding of `ItemsSource` or just placing `ToggleButton`s in it?

Comment: I am binding data through itemsource which have a collection of ****Class 
which is having propertis like
1)Enable(to check or uncheck)
2)Label -->Id.
<telerik:RadToggleButton  IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}" Width="45" Content="{Binding Label}" >

Comment: So do these items contain an index property or how do you identify which item should be highlighted? Do they contain any identifier? Do you have a separate property for the item to be highlighted?

Comment: I want something like itemsControl.[label]=>highlight backbround color to yellow

Comment: yes !I have a separate property which needs to be highlighted

Comment: Ok, so according to your latest edits, do you just want to button to turn yellow when it is toggled or do you want to highlight a button by index from your view model? These are two different things. It alo makes a difference, if you want to highlight a single item or multiple items.

Comment: Sounds odd. Why aren't you simply using a ListBox, which supports *selection* of item? It has a mode where only a single item can be selected. Alternatively, you may perhaps also use RadioButtons.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your item collection in your view model is `MyItemsCollection` and your items are of type `MyItem`. Add a property `TargetItem` property to your view model to identify the item to highlight.

```
private MyItem _highlightedItem;
public MyItem HighlightedItem
{
   get => _highlightedItem;
   set
   {
      if (_highlightedItem!= value)
      {
         _highlightedItem = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
}
```

Create a simple multi-value converter which compares objects for equality and returns a `bool`.

```
public class EqualityToBooleanConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return values[0] == values[1];
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("This is a one-way conversion.");
   }
}
```

You can add it to the resource dictionary of your `ItemsControl`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsCollection}" ...>
   <ItemsControl.Resources>
      <local:EqualityToBooleanConverter x:Key="EqualityToBooleanConverter"/>
   </ItemsControl.Resources>
   <!-- ...your other code. -->
</ItemsControl>
```

Create a `DataTrigger` in your `DataTemplate` to highlight a `ToggleButton` depending on the `HighlightedItem` property in your view model.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyItem}">
   <ToggleButton Content="{Binding Id}"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Enabled">
      <ToggleButton.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Value="True">
                  <DataTrigger.Binding>
                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityToBooleanConverter}">
                        <Binding/>
                        <Binding Path="DataContext.HighlightItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}"/>
                     </MultiBinding>
                  </DataTrigger.Binding>
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ToggleButton.Style>
   </ToggleButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now you can just set the `HighlightedItem` to the target item that you access by its index in the `MyItemsCollection` in your view model.

```
HighlightedItem = MyItemsCollection[24];
```

As a note, if the item to highlight actually is meant to be a selected item, then consider using a `Selector` control like `ListBox`. Then you can just use the `IsSelected` property of its containers.

Comment: Thanks, for the help but I have one concern here, let's say I have clicked 24 then toggle button 24 is highlighted.
but when I clicked another button now both 24 and other button is highlighted at a time only one button should be highlighted.

Comment: @Nikhil Please state these details clearly in your question. I have adapted the answer.